# Curl url txt file, but grep each url separately from single file

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, sed, pipe, curl

I have a text file with lots of url's in it. I'm using

```
curl -K "$urls" > $output
```

to spit the output to my output file. Now for the output of each separate url there is a term, let's say "mortgage", beneath which I do not want any more of the info. Now I know that I can use

```
sed '/mortgage/q'
```

to remove all info below the term "mortgage" but if I use it within my script like so

```
curl -K "$urls" | sed '/mortgage/q' > $output
```

it removes everything from the entire output below the first instance of "mortgage" from the output of first url in the $urls, but this wipes all of the info from the other url's (including the stuff before their own instance of the word "mortgage") due to the fact that it is working on the entire output, and not for each url.

How can I specify the  `sed '/mortgage/q'` to act separately on the output of each url in the url file so that it does not affect the output globally?

My url file is pretty simple, in the format (this is just an example):

```
URL = http://www.bbc.co.uk/sport/rugby-union/34914911

URL = http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9084453/simple-script-to-check-if-a-webpage-has-been-updated
```

and so on.....

I've conceived a hypothetical way of achieving this but not sure of the code - is there any way I can adapt the  `curl -K "$urls" | sed '/mortgage/q' > $output` command so that the command loops back after each subsequent url in the `$url` file i.e. So that the curl command initially just retrieves the first url in the file, performs the `sed` command on that url material, appends to `$output`, then loops back to the second url in the file, perform the sed command, append to `$output` and so on.... This would mean the required material from each url was included in the output file, but the stuff below 'mortgage' in each url was not. I just don't know how to achieve this with code. Any ideas?

Comment: I can think of an approach but it depends whether your $urls file just has a list of urls or whether it has other curl parameters. Can you show a snip/example of it?

Comment: hi gogoud, i've edited the original post with this info, cheers

Comment: where's *mortgage* then?

Comment: mortgage is just an example, as are the url's I have used in the query

Comment: how can anybody know what you're talking about? your examples do not include anything like the case you say you want to avoid, an example of which you gave as *mortgage*. we have no idea why you might consider `sed /mortgage/q` to be adequate in some cases but inadequate in others because we have no context for your problem. you have provided us with input you *want* *(i guess)* not the problematic input you *have*. how can any answer solve a problem to which it is not privy?

Comment: I've given examples and my question states this pretty clearly.  Everyone else understands, if you don't I suggest taking on another question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do it in two lines:

```
sed -n 's/\s*URL\s*=\s*\(.*\)/\1/p' /tmp/curl.conf|xargs -I {} curl -O "{}"
sed -n 's/\s*URL\s*=\s*\(.*\)/\1/p' /tmp/curl.conf|xargs -I {} basename "{}"|xargs -I {} sed '/mortgage/q' "{}"
```

The first sed command on each line extracts the URLs from your urls file (/tmp/curl.conf in the example). In the first line we use curl's -O option to save the output from each page into a file that has the page's name. In the second line we re-examine each of those files and show only the text you are interested in. Of course if the word 'mortgage' doesn't occur in a file then the whole file will be output.

This will leave you with a temporary file for each url in the current directory.

EDIT:

here's a short script that avoids any left-over files, it outputs the result to standard output, you can redirect it from there as you wish:

```
#!/bin/bash
TMPF=$(mktemp)
# sed command extracts URLs line by line
sed -n 's/\s*URL\s*=\s*\(.*\)/\1/p' /tmp/curl.conf >$TMPF
while read URL; do
    # retrieve each web page and delete any text after 'mortgage' (substitute whatever test you like)
    curl "$URL" 2>/dev/null | sed '/mortgage/q'
done <"$TMPF"
rm "$TMPF"
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion gogoud. The only concern I have with this is the creation of a separate file for each url. Ideally I need a single output file as I will be performing further global cleaning of the resulting data and having it in separate files may get messy. I suppose with your suggestion I could then introduce a command to join the data from the separate outputs in a single file, but I will wait and see if anyone provides a simpler solution before I accept this answer. Thanks again.

Comment: I added a short script which outputs a single stream of data and avoids any leftover files

Comment: gogoud- ok mate, gonna try this now, will get back to you, thanks.

Comment: Thanks gogoud, that is working nicely, thanks for your input, i've accepted your answer :)

Answer (score 0):

This general trick works even if your curl config file contains miscellaneous options such as user-agent, referer, etc.

First step, assume your config file named **curl_config**, then use `awk '/^[Uu][Rr][Ll]/{print;print "output = dummy/"++k;next}1' curl_config  > curl_config2`  to create a new curl config file which incremently append different output file names under each url/URL:

Example:

```
[xiaobai@xiaobai curl]$ cat curl_config
URL = "www.google.com"
user-agent = "holeagent/5.0"

url = "m12345.google.com"
user-agent = "holeagent/5.0"

URL = "googlevideo.com"
user-agent = "holeagent/5.0"
[xiaobai@xiaobai curl]$ awk '/^[Uu][Rr][Ll]/{print;print "output = dummy/"++k;next}1' curl_config  > curl_config2 
[xiaobai@xiaobai curl]$ cat curl_config2
URL = "www.google.com"
output = dummy/1
user-agent = "holeagent/5.0"

url = "m12345.google.com"
output = dummy/2
user-agent = "holeagent/5.0"

URL = "googlevideo.com"
output = dummy/3
user-agent = "holeagent/5.0"
[xiaobai@xiaobai curl]$
```

Then `mkdir dummy` to create a directory to hold this temporary files. Create `inotifywait` session(Replace the sed '/google/q' with your sed '/mortgage/q'):

```
[xiaobai@xiaobai curl]$ rm -r dummy; mkdir dummy;
[xiaobai@xiaobai curl]$ rm final 
[xiaobai@xiaobai curl]$ inotifywait -m dummy -e close_write | while read path action file; do echo "[$file]">> final ; sed '/google/q' "$path$file" >> final; echo "$path$file"; rm "$path$file"; done;
Setting up watches.
Watches established.
```

Open another bash/terminal session, rm **final** file if exist, then run your curl with your curl_config2 file created in first step above:

```
[xiaobai@xiaobai curl]$ curl -vLK curl_config2
...processing
```

Now take a look to inotifywait session, it will print the latest close written file, sed it and remove it immediately once done:

```
[xiaobai@xiaobai curl]$ inotifywait -m dummy -e close_write | while read path action file; do echo "[$file]">> final ; sed '/google/q' "$path$file" >> final; echo "$path$file"; rm "$path$file"; done;
Setting up watches.
Watches established.
dummy/1
dummy/3
```

Finally you can observe your output named **final**, The **[1 and 3]** separator is generated from `echo "[$file]">> final` above:

[image]

The reason of remove file immediately is because i assume your output file is large plus many url have to proceed, so it could save disk space to remove it immediately.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response, I appreciate the effort you've put in there, but I feel a simpler solution may be possible. I have added some info to the bottom of my original post (see NEW EDIT section) with a hypothetical way I may achieve my goal, but I am unsure of the correct code still.

Comment: Some of the urls require different options to make it works (e.g. you must provide user-agent when request google), and that's why curl config file exist(i'm not sure how you get it though). And i prefer to provide general solution(with curl config file) which might help someone else, rather than specific to read line by line with strip first 6 characters "URL = ", such as `while read -r line; do [ -z "$line" ] && continue; curl -vL "${line:6}" | sed '/mortgage/q' >> "results" ; done < curl_config` .